# How strong must an NPC be if I know they can throw a car?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

I'm trying to build a certain character in M&M 3E.  I've run into some limits due to not knowing the extent of their abilities (the source material is a series of web videos, which totals 45 minutes).

The character is a bruiser and a tank - they don't really take damage from anything in the show, and they are portrayed as being super strong.  The only real display of this super-strength (other than some very impressive leaps) is that the character is said to have thrown a car.

I'm assuming it's a full-sized sedan, and that it was thrown somewhat far - at least 30 feet.

I've looked over the Deluxe Heroes Handbook, but it simply mentions that your strength determines how much you can lift, carry, or throw.  It doesn't give any indication of how strong you have to be to throw a car (Mass rank 7).

Comment: Let me guess: Captain Hammer?

Comment: [Related] [Would throwing cars and debris require Thrown Strike or Blast?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/28037/would-throwing-cars-and-debris-require-thrown-strike-or-blast)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Yeah, found that during my search.  This isn't something that is a common use for the character, and I wasn't intending for it to be built as a power, but rather as a measure of how strong he'd have to be.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Yes.  Don't tell my players, but I ***have plans***.  I'm guessing he works out at around PL8, but I need a benchmark for his strength to be sure that works without damage-shifting too much.

Comment: If you have your players sing at any moment, WE NEED VIDEO EVIDENCE OF THE EVENTS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The average weight of a car in the United States is around 4,000 pounds (see [here](http://www.nytimes.com/2004/05/05/business/05weight.html)) and Throw Distance is equal to Strength Rank - Mass Rank (p 12 Deluxe Hero's Handbook or [Ranks and Measures in the online SRD](http://www.d20herosrd.com/home/ranks-and-measures)), so the Captain here will need a Strength Rank of +7 to throw an average weight car 30 feet (rank 7 - rank 7 = rank 0 = 30 feet).  If the car was about a thousand pounds lighter, it could be thrown the same distance with Strength Rank 6 (rank 6 - rank 6 = rank 0 = 30 feet).  Check the Measurements table on page 11 of the Deluxe Hero's Handbook or the above link for the SRD for more information on distance.

Comment: You beat me to it, but I suggested additions to also link to the SRD.

Comment: Thank you.  Somehow I missed those three sentences in the book.

Comment: @Jeff: Honestly, I don't blame you. The organization in the 3E handbooks is a bit shoddy. Important facts are scattered all over the place.